# Issues reindexing a dataframe with dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been working with this code for a few days and have been having issues relating to reindexing this dataframe. I am extracting game logs for MLB players and formatting them for my purposes in order to export them to excel. I am attempting to have a row for every date between April 2nd and October 1st (the 2017 MLB regular season), adding a blank row for each date that that player did not play. Earlier today this code actually worked when using one url but when I tried using it with multiple urls in a loop, the output was blank. When I comment the line out that reindexes the dataframe with the dates the code runs properly.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import datetime
import re
import numpy as np


start_date = '2017-04-02'
end_date = '2017-10-01'
idx = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
dates = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in idx]

url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx?playerid=7859&position=OF&type=1&gds=2017-04-02&gde=2017-10-01&season='
resp = requests.get(url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class' : 'rgMasterTable'})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]


top2rows = df[0:1]
df = df.replace(['Total','Date'], np.nan).dropna()
df = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
df.set_index(df.columns[0],inplace=True)
#df = df.reindex(dates)
df = pd.concat([top2rows, df], ignore_index=False, join='inner')
```

This is the traceback code when I run it with the second reindex row not commented out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Fangraphs Bug Fixer.py", line 36, in <module>
df = df.reindex(dates)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2733, in reindex
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2515, in reindex
fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2679, in _reindex_axes
fill_value, limit, tolerance)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2690, in _reindex_index
allow_dups=False)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2627, in _reindex_with_indexers
copy=copy)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3886, in reindex_indexer
self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2836, in _can_reindex
raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: does the index of `df` have duplicate dates?

Comment: Actually I had not thought about that, but it does. Due to the occasional double header there are some instances where one date appears twice. This makes the process a bit more complicated